# How to get Messenger contact list through .NET

Tags: c#, .net, api, msn-messenger

I want to be able to get the list of Messenger contacts of a certain user through .NET.
I've seen [Messenger Connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/default.aspx), but it's still under beta and with limited access.

Any ideas for easier alternatives? I thought it would be as easy as invoking a WCF service.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is the [Windows Live User Data APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc305075.aspx), which contains the [Windows Live Contacts API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463989.aspx). See the documentation on [retrieving contacts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463933.aspx).

Keep in mind that the API is considered deprecated, and will eventually be replaced by Messenger Connect. See this [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/messengerconnect/thread/3b6e1366-76ad-48c6-8770-481696bcf4da) for more information on a possible timeframe for the service being discontinued.

Answer (score 1):

Try Jbuddy from Zion Software, multiprotocol support.